# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to do a carousel with slick but it doesn't work.

This test code work well:

```
<script  src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
</script>
```

But this code don't work and reply me **$(...).slick is not a function** :

```
<script src="js/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/logo-appear.js"></script>
<script src="js/skill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.experiences').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
</script>
```

I tried to update the version of jQuery, 
to insert **$(document).ready(function(){});**

I'm not really good with jQuery, maybe there is a conflict with waypoint.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try removing waypoint and see what happens then?

Comment: when i remove others js files it reply me " $ is not defined "

Comment: Just remove waypoint.

Comment: Also, can you post any other relevant code? There isn't enough here to find the problem.

Comment: isn't your file in the following instead: `js/slick.min.js`?

Comment: it reply me waypoint is not defined because i use waypoint on logo-appear and skill.js

Comment: What is in skill.js?

Comment: its for another section in my website and im using waypoint to appear the elements on scroll.

Comment: tell me what part of my code you need and i will edit my post

Comment: @AliSheikhpour no it's in the slick folder at the root

Answer (score 1):

You do need to guarantee that the Slick library is loaded before you try to use the `slick()` function. You were on the right track by considering the need for to wait until the document is "ready", as that will ensure that the Slick and jQuery libraries have been fetched. You can use the jQuery `$()` shorthand to check this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.experiences').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        cssEase: 'linear'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to jQuery **slim** version.

Cross check how many jQuery being loaded